# Custom JQuery Mobile Button

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3, and attempted to follow a [tutorial](https://hiddentao.com/archives/2011/11/07/how-to-write-a-custom-widget-for-jquery-mobile/) in order to create my own custom widget.

I'm getting stuck on the very first step, and I'm not sure if I'm following the right example for the right version of jQuery mobile.

There is no error on the page, my element is just never enriched.

```js
(function($) {
    $.widget("mobile.target", $.mobile.button, {
        /** Available options for the widget are specified here, along with default values. */
        options: {
            inline: false,
            mode: "default",
            height: 200
        },
        /** Mandatory method - automatically called by jQuery Mobile to initialise the widget. */
        _create: function() {
            var inputElement = this.element;
            var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
            $(document).trigger("targetcreate");

            inputElement.after("<button>" + inputElement.val() + "</button>");

        },
        /** Custom method to handle updates. */
        _update: function() {
            var inputElement = this.element;
            var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
            $(document).trigger("targetupdate");

            inputElement.siblings("button").text(inputElement.val());

        },
        /* Externally callable method to force a refresh of the widget. */
        refresh: function() {
            return this._update();
        }
    });
    /* Handler which initialises all widget instances during page creation. */
    $(document).bind("pagecreate", function(e) {
        $(document).trigger("targetbeforecreate");
        return $(":jqmData(role='target')", e.target).target();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" data-role="target" value="inp1">
<input type="button" value="inp2">
<div data-role="target">div1</div>
<div type="button">div2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("mobile.target", $.mobile.button, {
        /** Available options for the widget are specified here, along with default values. */
        options: {
            inline: false,
            mode: "default",
            height: 200
        },
        /** Mandatory method - automatically called by jQuery Mobile to initialise the widget. */
        _create: function() {
            var inputElement = this.element;
            var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
            $(document).trigger("targetcreate");

            inputElement.after("<button>" + inputElement.val() + "</button>");

        },
        /** Custom method to handle updates. */
        _update: function() {
            var inputElement = this.element;
            var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
            $(document).trigger("targetupdate");

            inputElement.siblings("button").text(inputElement.val());

        },
        /* Externally callable method to force a refresh of the widget. */
        refresh: function() {
            return this._update();
        }
    });
    /* Handler which initialises all widget instances during page creation. */
    $(document).bind("pagecreate", function(e) {
        $(document).trigger("targetbeforecreate");
        return $(":jqmData(role='target')", e.target).target();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Expected output was a custom JQueryMobile button that inherits from the JQueryMobile button. Not just a tiny html5 button in a div. e.g. Div1 rendering the same as Div2 but with customized changes made.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: also add the tutorial which you followed

Comment: I added an answer for you @RyanTheLeach

Comment: @SagarV Added a better example of the html, as well as the expected output.

Comment: Why are you using 1.3?

Comment: @Omar It's what we are currently using, I tried to migrate up earlier, but my knowledge on jqm isn't concrete enough for that to have gone well.

Comment: I'm not sure if 1.3 is still supported now. Anyway, I recommend upgrading to 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an `input` element in jQuery code. But you defined a `div` element in the HTML page.
That is the problem. Change it to `input`.

Check the below code

The tutorial you followed states that only use the `:jqmData` if you didn't use the HTML5 data attribute. Remove it

```js
(function($) {
  $.widget("mobile.target", $.mobile.widget, {

    options: {
      inline: false,
      mode: "default",
      height: 200
    },
    _create: function() {
      var inputElement = this.element;
      var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
      $(document).trigger("targetcreate");
      inputElement.after("<button>"+inputElement.val()+"</button>");
    },
    _update: function() {
      var inputElement = this.element;
      var opts = $.extend(this.options, inputElement.data("options"));
      $(document).trigger("targetupdate");
      inputElement.siblings("button").text(inputElement.val());
    },
    refresh: function() {
      return this._update();
    }
  });
  $(document).bind("pagecreate", function(e) {
    $(document).trigger("mywidgetbeforecreate");
    return $("[role='target']", e.target).target();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" data-role="target" value="inp1">
  <input type="button" value="inp2">
  <div type="button" data-role="target">div1</div>
  <div type="button">div2</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly is it looking for only an input? I thought this.element was the thing being bound to data role target, and didn't relate to the element type whatsoever

Comment: `inputElement.val()` this code. `div` can't have a value attribute. The script will break there. @RyanTheLeach

Comment: Hope you got it @RyanTheLeach

Comment: The rendered output looks a lot like jquery mobiles normal enrichment for inputs is still happening though. The JavaScript code in your answer is identical to mine, all that's changed is that you are using 'input'. The jquery demo has examples of widgets that can be attached to input buttons, anchors, divs and more. Nor is there any citation on whether this is the correct method. Sorry for being picky, but there is bounty on the line :(

Comment: I suspect I didn't explain myself well enough, so I have added a line explaining the expected output.

Comment: Please wait. I will look into it as soon as I reach office.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach _ can be attached to input buttons, anchors, divs and more._ true. but here, the problem is that you selected a `div` element and then use jQuery's `val()` function. Which will return nothing. a `div` can't have a `value`.

Comment: Sure. But it doesn't error. That's not the problem. That could be replaced with a static string in this example and it would still not look like jQuery's buttons that I need to inherit from.

Comment: can you add an image representation of _custom inherited button_? What type of inheriting you look for?

Comment: Quoted from the question: " e.g. Div1 rendering the same as Div2 but with customized changes made." div1 is clearly not looking anything like div2 at the moment.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach please check the new answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147320/discussion-between-ryan-the-leach-and-sagar-v).